# After getting voted up on my question I am not notified & confused

Tags: support, bug

My question got 22 votes up, but there is only 190 reputation points... better see the pics...
All votes are counted about last 4 hours (today).

**Picture One**

[image]

**Picture Two**

[image]

Comment: You've hit the reputation cap, congratulations! This means there will be no more reputation gains, and it's the reputation gains that'll make the notification. If I were to downvote one of your posts and someone else upvotes one of your posts, you get a notification again (one that says +2) :)

Comment: The Mortarboard badge you got indicates you hit the cap for the first time. Congratulations!