# Curious badge display 3/5 instead of 4/5

Tags: discussion, support, bug, badges

I have asked well-received 4 questions on 4 separate days but its display 3/5 instead of 4/5 in this network.

**Date:**  Dec 16 '20 at 11:20, Dec 17 '20 at 11:42, Dec 4 '20 at 9:01, 2 days ago,

**Note** one of them was close then reopen. Maybe it was cause of miscalculation …
I am not sure it’s bug or not

**Looking for clarifications**

[image]

Comment: Strangely enough, you have 18 questions, so there is something that might've caused that error.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe the badge tracks *days*, not the number of questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How this works is that since there are 18 questions, each could be counted with the Curious badge within the days of posting. If one question gets negatively received whilst another gets positively received, the amount of days might be ruined. I have no other explanaitions.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe no need to tell me, I have written several answers on how this works here on MSE as well as on MSO :-) Any day on which *all* questions posted that day were received positively, counts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question was asked on December 16th as well, but it's closed: [After getting voted up on my question I am not notified & confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358058/295232)

Hence December 16th doesn't count towards the Curious badge. *All* your questions on that day must be well-received. A closed question doesn't count, even if it has a positive score.

Comment: Good clarification Glorfindel, the badge description could be clearer in this case. I also thought that just **one** well-received question per day sufficed.